# How to render a partial for tag in Ghost?

Tags: handlebars.js, ghost-blog

When a user is viewing a tag on my blog, I'd like to be able to display additional information about that tag. I think it would be nice to have a template that's called for each tag I have.

My **tag.hbs**

```
{{!< default}}

<div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns">
    <h1 class="archive_title"><span>{{tag.name}}</span></h1>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- PLEASE LOOK HERE -->
I would like to render a partial here
<!-- PLEASE LOOK HERE -->

<div class="row {{#if @blog.cover}}margintop{{/if}}">

  <div class="small-12 large-9 columns">
    {{#foreach posts}}
    {{> content-post}}
    {{/foreach}}
  </div>

  <div class="small-12 large-3 columns">
    {{> sidebar}}
  </div>

</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 columns">
    {{pagination}}
  </div>
</div>
```

To render a partial for the current tag name, I've tried using this

```
{{> tag.name}}
```

I get a 500 error

```
[tag.hbs] The partial tag.name could not be found
```

Is there a way to include a partial with a dynamic name in handlebars?

---

**Additional question:** Ideally, I'd like all of the tag partials in their own directory. Is this possible too?

Answer (score 2):

I am quite new to the Ghost platform, but I have been experimenting quite a bit. I see that you attempted to do this:

```
{{> tag.name}}
```

That is not actually calling the name for that particular tag, what you were trying to do there was to actually show the contents of the tag.hbs file itself. The reason I claim this is because when I recently just created a "menu.hbs" for a menu bar for my theme I attempted this:

```
{{> menu}}
```

Handlebars quickly realized that I had a "menu.hbs" file and poured the contents of that file onto the spot that I placed "{{>menu}}" in.

Essentially what you are trying to attempt is a "path". If you scroll down to "Handlebars Paths" on the [Handlebars webpage](http://handlebarsjs.com) you will find exactly the method you were trying to attempt. I hope this at least helped a little.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
{{#has tag="foo"}}
  {{> partial-for-foo}}
{{/has}}
{{#has tag="bar"}}
  {{> partial-for-bar}}
{{/has}}
```

See the [has helper docs](https://themes.ghost.org/v0.11.1/docs/has).